# send post from webpage to Node.js server ...do not use 'fetch'...?

Tags: html, node.js, http-post

I am using the following javascript on a webpage to send information to a Node.js server upon a "click" on an image.  This is using a 'POST' request.

```
<script>

function rerouter(_sent) {

 var _people = <%- JSON.stringify(member_list) %>;  
   //convert the passed ('member_list') array into a JSON string...
 var _attend = <%- JSON.stringify(online) %>;  
   //convert the passed ('online') array into a JSON string...

 var splits = _sent.id.split("_");  //"split" on "underscore ('_')"

  if (_people.indexOf(splits[1]) != -1) {

  //**SEND INFO TO SERVER...

  var available = _attend[_people.indexOf(splits[1])];  

  var response = fetch("members/pages/:" + splits[1] + "/presence/:" + available, {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
   }
  });

  //**

  }  //'_people' array contains the member name ('splits[1]')...

 }

 </script>
```

And here I handle the request in my Node.js server code:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.post('/members/pages/:membername/presence/:online', urlencodedParser,  function (req, res) {
console.log("I RECEIVED FROM CLIENT THE FOLLOWING:")
console.log(req.params)
console.log(req.body)

res.redirect('/_landing');
})
```

Here is my console output:

```
I RECEIVED FROM CLIENT THE FOLLOWING:
{ membername: ':Nica', online: ':Yes' }
{}
```

As can be seen from my output, the POST route does seem to be functional, somewhat.  However my 'redirect' command does NOT execute...the webpage does not change to the '_landing' page as it should...I think it may be because I am using 'fetch' to send the POST request...???  Can somebody verify if that is the cause (or another issue is the cause) and how I might be able to correct the issue?

In addition why does my 'params' include the colons (":") when I log to the console...is that standard?  I would not think it would include the colons in the log, only the actual data.

Basically it seems my POST is almost working...but not exactly.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

UPDATE:  I have made some changes and my POST seems to be working fine now.  In my frontend webpage I use the following to make the HTTP POST request:

```
<script>

function rerouter(_sent) {

 var _people = <%- JSON.stringify(member_list) %>;  
   //convert the passed ('member_list') array into a JSON string...
 var _attend = <%- JSON.stringify(online) %>;  
   //convert the passed ('online') array into a JSON string...

 var splits = _sent.id.split("_");  //"split" on "underscore ('_')"

  if (_people.indexOf(splits[1]) != -1) {

  //**SEND INFO TO SERVER...

  var available = _attend[_people.indexOf(splits[1])];  

  fetch('/members/pages/callup', {
   method: 'post',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({name: splits[1], presence: available, str: 'Some string: &=&'})
  })

  //**

  }  //'_people' array contains the member name ('splits[1]')...

 }

 </script>
```

...And modified my route handler in my Node.js script:

```
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.post('/members/pages/callup', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
console.log("I RECEIVED FROM CLIENT THE FOLLOWING:")
console.log(req.body)

res.redirect('/_landing');
})
```

This is functional...to receive the data sent from the frontend webpage.

The only remaining problem is why does the 'redirect' not fire...???  I still have a feeling that by using a 'fetch' that somehow this is interfering with the page redirection...?  A fetch would normally be used to wait for a response from the server, in my case I am not interested in that functionality I just want to send data one-way from frontend to backend...and then redirect the frontend page.  I cannot think of any other reason why the redirect does not fire...?

Comment: Do you have the `body-parser` module in your `app.js` (express code)?

Comment: Yes I do...should I include it in my route?  Something like 'app.post('/members/pages/:membername/presence/:online', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {'  ...where the 'urlencodedParser' is defined as 'var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })'...??  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I gave that a try...the only difference I see is that the 'req.body' console log is no longer 'undefined'...it is just empty ('{ }')...I edited my post above to reflect the changes I made

Comment: @panjit Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `extented:true` instead of false as,

`var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })` and move this line above of the below statement,

`var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()` and check if it works.

And finally change your headers here from,

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'
}
```

To,

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I made some changes and updated my post accordingly.  I have the exchange of data using the POST working now.  However for some reason the 'redirect' within my route handler still does not execute.  I am at a loss to explain why.

Comment: Try `window.location.assign('/_landing')` instead of your `res.redirect('/_landing')`. Hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes I tried that, and it works to redirect just fine.  Although I used 'window.location.replace('/_landing')' instead.  Still a bit frustrating to have to do it client-side.  Would like to know why that is...I think the 'fetch' is acting as some sort of 'blocking' function.  Anyway thank you for your inputs, much appreciated!